# I need make a subquery

Tags: sql, count, group-by, subquery, h2

I have two tables: invitations and events.

I need get the name of the event, the total of guest per event and the total of presents when its true per event in the same query!

Something like join both tables (left join) selecting events.name, count(invitations.guest), count(invitations.presents when = true) and group it by events...

Looking the tables data...

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/360112/Duda/invitaciones.jpg]
[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/360112/Duda/eventos.jpg]

I think it could work but I don't get what I want...

```
SELECT e.name, count(in.guest) as Guests, (SELECT count(presents) 
FROM watermelon.invitations WHERE presents = true) as Presents 
FROM watermelon.events e LEFT JOIN watermelon.invitations in ON e.id = in.event 
GROUP BY in.event;
```

Then I get:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/360112/Duda/resultado.jpg

Some suggestion? Please I need it, and I'm tired of trying and getting wrong results... 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format the question better next time.  :) Also the link to your drop box is broken.

Comment: Oh! I'll be aware of that next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this using `COUNT`, `GROUP BY` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT E.Id, 
    E.Name, 
    COUNT(I.Id) TotalGuests,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN I.Presents = 'TRUE' THEN 1 END) TotalPresents
FROM Events E
    LEFT JOIN Invitations I ON E.Id = I.Event
GROUP BY E.Id, E.Name
```

I'm not positive about your data type of Presents, but this should be close.  Also using a `LEFT JOIN` to return all events.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly! Please, could you tell me where can I find more information about those methods and keywords u used in the query?

Comment: @Jamr -- np, glad we could help!  CASE statements works much like IF statements -- if Presents = 'True' then count the record, else don't  (actually else return null and if you attempt to count null, it counts as 0).  You can string multiple WHEN statements together (else if) which makes for nice comparisons.  Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your subquery
`(SELECT count(presents) FROM watermelon.invitations WHERE presents = true)`

isn't doing any filtering; it's just counting all the records in the table with a true everytime it's called. The query below should do it the way you need. It's the exact same query you had except that I added the "and subq.event=e.id" criteria, which restricts the subquery to the data for that particular record only:
`SELECT e.name, count(in.guest) as Guests, (SELECT count(subq.presents) 
    FROM watermelon.invitations as subq WHERE subq.presents = true and subq.event=e.id) as Presents 
    FROM watermelon.events e LEFT JOIN watermelon.invitations in ON e.id = in.event 
    GROUP BY in.event;`